# Click on icon in taskbar may not lead to setting application to foreground

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, taskbar

Just few days ago I've faced with a nasty problem - after I click on any icon in Windows Taskbar nothing happens except for icon blinking (though application should be brought to foreground). I've spent some time for investigation trying to fix this problem, but no avail.

Here is what I figured out:

- This issue happens only with x86 applications on Win64 for me.
- Spy++ says me that after i click on icon it receives strange message `VSM_TRYRESTOREFOCUS` and then multiple times `0x0118` message (looks like `WM_TIMER` but Spy++ can't detect what it is and calls it 'unknown').

My first thought this is Windows hook from some nasty application, but I have almost the same application set on another PC and everything works alright. If you have ever faced with something similar I would be very grateful for any suggestions. Please do not hesitate to ask clarifications.

P.S. The only difference between my computers that on the problematic one I have two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.  It could be running off the screen (esp with multi-monitor setup). Try the following steps

- Move your mouse over app icon on task bar, to see the thumbnail of application pop-up.
- Right-click on thumbnail
- Select 'Move' option
- Use arrow keys on keyboard until you spot the window on foreground.

Good luck!

Comment: Fortunately this issue has gone after I had cleaned up all excessive software and updated rest of it. So I suppose that this is not a native Windows bug. But surely, I will check this workaround if the problem return.